# Google text-to-speech - Google::Cloud::InternalError (13:Internal error encountered.):

Tags: google-text-to-speech

I have Google Text to Speech up and running in my application. Most of the time the API works perfectly, and I'm receiving audio file responses that play fine.

Sometimes though I receive the following error:

```
Google::Cloud::InternalError (13:Internal error encountered.):
```

I have safeguards in place to prevent my app from running into usage quotas so I don't think it's that. Also, before I had these safeguards in place, if I did go over quotas the error messages said you were over your quota.

Does anyone know what this message means?

Alternatively, if someone knows a good way to handle this error gracefully (it's a Rails app).

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Ok so I don't know what exactly is going wrong on Google's side other than some sort of internal error. However, I did come up with a solution to rescue the error and allows me to continue my text to speech job.

Here is what my code looks like for those interested:

```
def convert_to_audio(text, gender)
    client = Google::Cloud::TextToSpeech.text_to_speech

    input_text = { text: text }

    # Note: the voice can also be specified by name.
    # Names of voices can be retrieved with client.list_voices
    # https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/voices
    if gender == 'MALE'
      name = 'en-US-Standard-D'
    else
      name = 'en-US-Standard-E'
    end
    voice = {
      language_code: "en-US",
      name: name,
      ssml_gender:   gender
    }

    audio_config = { audio_encoding: "MP3" }

    begin
      retries ||= 0
      response = client.synthesize_speech(
        input: input_text,
        voice: voice,
        audio_config: audio_config
      )
    rescue Google::Cloud::InternalError
      puts "The Google error occurred"
      retry if (retries += 1) < 3
    end
```

Basically now when I get that error from Google I retry the synthesize speech call.

Google has pretty tight quotas set on this API, and I'm guessing this is because larger and more frequent requests tend to throw errors more often, so they're trying to do quality control.

I did also find this error mapping for those interested:

```
namespace error {
// These values must match error codes defined in google/rpc/code.proto.
enum Code {
  OK = 0,
  CANCELLED = 1,
  UNKNOWN = 2,
  INVALID_ARGUMENT = 3,
  DEADLINE_EXCEEDED = 4,
  NOT_FOUND = 5,
  ALREADY_EXISTS = 6,
  PERMISSION_DENIED = 7,
  UNAUTHENTICATED = 16,
  RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED = 8,
  FAILED_PRECONDITION = 9,
  ABORTED = 10,
  OUT_OF_RANGE = 11,
  UNIMPLEMENTED = 12,
  INTERNAL = 13,
  UNAVAILABLE = 14,
  DATA_LOSS = 15,
};
}  // namespace error
```